# why currently not working firebug in windows 7

Tags: firebug

Suddenly why firebug is not installing in windows 7 ?why they are showing that "your device is not compatible for download this(firebug)"?

Comment: my guess is they dropped support for an outdated OS. We are only 2 years away from Microsoft dropping support for even security updates for Windows 7.

Comment: which windows version would be compatible for firebug do you think?

Comment: Windows 8+ probably.

Comment: Firebug has been replaced by built-in dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug's development is [officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) for quite some time now in favor of the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools).

On profiles where it is already installed, it [stops working with Firefox 57](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/), because starting from that version of Firefox only [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) are supported.